# Indentify system load on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, scalability

I have a tomcat server running my web application: http://www.LoudReview.com.
It is a limited hosting account with 128 MB of memory allowed.
Time and again, the connection to the tomcat server times out.

I want to know if there is a way I can monitor the load on the tomcat server in order to reduce the memory-intensive operations when the system is under high load. Can I build some intelligence so that I can monitor the amount of memory being used by the system, or the number of connections already occupied, and accordingly process the requests?

I would prefer simple-to-implement solutions if possible, though I am OK with more complex methods as well.

Thanks

Comment: You have 128MiB for the JVM (heap) or for the entire machine (e.g. kernel, logging, userspace, etc.)? Or, are you on a shared machine with a total-process-memory-limit?

Comment: 128 MB is dedicated to tomcat only. Yes its a shared machine

Comment: Okay. What JVM startup parameters do you use (specifically, the heap-related ones)? When the server "times-out" (what does that mean?) does the JVM process still exist, or does the JVM go down? Anything in the log files -- specifically logs/catalina.out (or equivalent) or the system log (to see if you are suffering linux oome-killer).

Comment: Basically, the search engine crawlers keep crawling my website. So, sometimes, the no of requests becomes extremely high which chokes the server. I want to build an intelligence in the application so that it automcatically recognises if the system load(memory used & no of requests) is too high and accordingly do lesser amount of processing till the system load decreases

Comment: If there is a search-engine crawler putting strain on your server, you should complain. When we get crawled, it's usually like one request every few seconds or minutes. Which crawler is killing your site?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain system load average using JMX using the key `java.lang:type=OperatingSystem` and attribute `SystemLoadAverage`. The value will be a double-precision floating point value (aka 'double').

Note that the load average is the average length of the run queue during the sample period (and the number above might be instantaneous, or the 1-minute average). Depending on your system, your JVM process might only count as "1" no matter how many requests are waiting to be serviced. Thus, you may have a load average of 1.0 all the time (which suggests perfect CPU utilization) while the CPU is really thrashing-around servicing many requests that you can't detect.

If most of your requests are all the same "cost", then you might want to consider request throughput as a better measure of the "load" of your system. You can also get metrics like that through JMX, but you'll have to calculate your Connector's name (or just connect using `jconsole` and browse until you find it).

Tomcat's Connectors each have a JMX bean with the key `Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name="[protocol]-[connectortype]-[localip-?]-[portnum]`. An example is `Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name="http-nio-127.0.0.1-8217`. There are three attributes that are of use for you, here:

1. `maxTime`
2. `processingTime`
3. `requestCount`

You can either sample these values and keep track of your own load, or you can use the `resetCounters` operation on the bean to reset the counters and let the JMX bean keep all the metrics for you.